Getting 403 error only when using wireless connection
I have a .NET 4.5 web application hosted on IIS 8.5 running on win 2012 R2 server. I can access the web application over wifi, but some folks cannot. They can access web application only when they are connected via network cable. When on wifi, they get a 403 error.
In system logs I see this error - An SSL 3.0 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.
Any ideas what's going on? Is the above error related to 403 error?

People usually get started from IIS log files, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#log-file-locations and see which substatus code is there. But you are using an end of life Windows Server version, not others won't be able to reproduce and investigate.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
